# Is it correct to say that all NoSQL providers charge for read/write operations?

Tags: firebase, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I was reading an article about a Crowfunding campaign where the Developers failed to realize that Firebase Realtime Database was being unnecessarily queried multiple times, and that incurred in a 30K expense in less than 72 hours.

I know that Firebase Realtime Database charges read/write operations, and that DynamoDB charges not only per GB in disk space, but also read/write operations.

Is the read/write charging a constant thing between NoSQL providers's price models? Are there providers that wont bill you for the read/write operations?

Answer (score 0):

I found this video excellent to help dispel some myth and provide a great sense on how to manage cots. There is likely smart ways to set up you use case to not have significant costs unless you use case becomes extremely popular.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE

I hope this helps a little bit!